# Copy everything from one cell and paste it into a range (similar to ctrl + a then ctrl+c whilst clicking the formula bar) in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet that contains a bunch of cells that are populated by strings divided by spaces. When I click on the cell, press ctrl+a and then paste it to a range of the same size it works nicely, I want to emulate this process in VBA.

I tried creating my own function that took out these spaces, the issue is some of the entries I am trying to paste do in fact have spaces.

I also tried recording a macro but what it spat out is useless when I try and apply this to a large dataset. This is what happened:

```
Sub Macro4()
'
' Macro4 Macro
'

'
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "ProjId ProjDesc    ScenId  ScenDesc    CellId  ValDate UserId  ProjTyp ProjMode    etc etc etc etc etc....    Value240    " & _
        ""
    Sheets("sheet1").Select
    Range("F1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Completely useless as the next cell will have completely different entries.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: SAMPLE DATA:
Here is a simple image of what I am trying to achieve. The A column has every entry in a cell, I want it to look like what F:J has in it. Hope this clears things up 
[image: Image of sample data]

Comment: Can you post sample data and desired output?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad done, hth

Answer (score 0):

On the front of house, have you tried using trim for your white-space issue?

```
=trim("      Your    String     here")
```

becomes

```
="Your String Here"
```

This removes all the whitespace before your string starts which could be causing your copy/paste issues, see documentation here: [Documentation](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-trim-function)

Edit: Upon seeing your screenshot I think you should run text to column based on x, then run it again based on the the underscore _

Comment: Hi Ryan thanks for your answer. This isn't the issue I'm afraid when i click in the formula bar and press ctrl+a and ctrl+c and then select the row I want to paste in (in this case its F8:J8) it will work with the format it is currently in... the issue is making it automated as I have tens of thousands of cells with such data in). EDIT: I'm afriad your suggestion will not work either... it need not be 'x' everytime. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following excerpt of code would help you .... I have assumed here that you want the data displayed as you laid it out in the image.

```
Public Sub separateStuff()
Dim splitArr As Variant, x As Long, lastRow As Long, firstNum As Integer, secondNum As Integer, tmpVal As String

splitArr = Split(CStr(Range("A1").Value), Chr(10))
Range("F8:J8").Value = splitArr
lastRow = Cells(Cells.rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For x = 2 To lastRow
    tmpVal = CStr(Cells(x, 1).Value)
    firstNum = InStr(tmpVal, "X")
    secondNum = InStr(tmpVal, "_")
    Cells(8 + (x - 1), 6).Value = Mid(tmpVal, 1, firstNum)
    Cells(8 + (x - 1), 7).Value = Mid(tmpVal, firstNum + 1, secondNum - firstNum)
    Cells(8 + (x - 1), 10).Value = Mid(tmpVal, secondNum + 1, Len(tmpVal))
    Cells(8 + (x - 1), 10).NumberFormat = "mmm-yy"
Next x
Erase splitArr

End Sub
```